# Expression in EF Core where clause takes too much time

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I would like to apply a filter to my SQL function results:

```
var data = await DbSet.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyFunc](...)")
                      .Where(x => x.Field == "some value")
                      .ToListAsync();
```

This will work. But if I define an expression

```
Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> filter = (x) => x.Field == "some value"
```

and apply it in the `.Where` clause, then execution will take 2 minutes instead of 2 seconds. In my logs, I can see that the SQL was generated correctly (no server side filtering), but it take 2 minutes to generate query.

Where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Analyze generated SQL, its execution plan. EF Is doing what you have specified.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv generated sql is fine. It takes 2 seconds to execute it in SMMS. But sql generation itself takes a lot of time.

Comment: Then it can be Parameter Sniffing, when SQL Server choose not optimal execution plan based on parameters.